# How find out whether a graph is vertex transitive?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, group-theory

How can I use Mathematica to find out whether a graph is [vertex transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex-transitive_graph)?

Comment: This will be included in IGraph/M 0.4 (when it is released in a couple of months), for convenience.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sufficiently familiar with the involved mathematics, so perhaps this is not the best solution. But it should work:

```
dog = GraphData["DodecahedralGraph"]
```

First we find the graph's automorphism group.  (Reminder: if `GraphAutomorphismGroup` is too slow a for a graph, you can use `IGBlissAutomorphismGroup` from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).)

```
group = GraphAutomorphismGroup[dog]
```

We need to make sure that any vertex can be mapped to any other by some automorphism.  In other words, that all vertices belong to the same group orbit.

```
GroupOrbits[group] === {Range@VertexCount[dog]}
(* True *)
```

Wrapping it all up into a function, and considering special cases:

```
vertexTransitiveQ[g_?EmptyGraphQ] = True;
vertexTransitiveQ[g_ /; MultigraphQ[g] || MixedGraphQ[g]] = $Failed;
vertexTransitiveQ[g_?GraphQ] :=
  With[{elems = Range@VertexCount[g]},
    GroupOrbits[GraphAutomorphismGroup[g], elems] === {elems}
  ]
vertexTransitiveQ[_] = False;
```

---

**Update:**  This functionality is available as `IGVertexTransitiveQ` in the prerelease version of [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

Comment: Thank you. One more query. If I define

Comment: @cliveelphick Your question is cut off.

Comment: not sure if last comment received. If I let G=Part[GraphData[n],1] to select first named graph in Wolfram database with n vertices, and then use GraphAutomorphismGroup[GraphData[G]] i get the message that GraphAutomorphismGroup is "not  a valid group". how do I avoid this problem? Thank you. Clive

Comment: @cliveelphick  Please give a concrete `GraphData` command to get the problem graph (i.e. what is your `n`?)

Comment: @cliveelphick `GraphAutomorphismGroup@GraphData[GraphData[3][[1]]]` works fine in version 11.1.0, as well as 10.0.2. What is your version?

Comment: i think i am still on version 9. i have n=10.

Comment: @cliveelphick `GraphAutomorphismGroup` is not available in version 9.  Nor does IGraph/M work with it.

Comment: thank you i will upgrade. Clive